# Retrieve records till a certain point in SQL table data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of data as follows

```
ticketID    user    transdate
---------------------------------
101 serviceuser1    2019-06-03
101 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
101 systemuser      2019-06-04
101 serviceuser1    2019-06-04
101 serviceuser1    2019-06-05
102 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
102 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
102 serviceuser1    2019-06-05
102 systemuser      2019-06-06
103 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
103 serviceuser1    2019-06-03
103 systemuser      2019-06-06
103 serviceuser2    2019-06-06
```

I want to retrieve records only till user (systemuser) for each ticketID and eliminate the rest.

Expected result would be as follows

```
ticketID    user    transdate
-------------------------------
101 serviceuser1    2019-06-03
101 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
101 systemuser      2019-06-04
102 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
102 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
102 serviceuser1    2019-06-05
102 systemuser      2019-06-06
103 serviceuser2    2019-06-03
103 serviceuser1    2019-06-03
103 systemuser      2019-06-06
```

Tried doing ranking function like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ticketid, user,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY transdate partition by ticketid) AS rownumber 
     FROM TableName) AS temptable
```

This gives me ranking, after this how to filter the required rows. I am using standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag) FROM (
  SELECT *, 0 = COUNTIF(user = 'systemuser') OVER(win) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY ticketID ORDER BY transdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
) 
WHERE flag
```

when applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row ticketID    user            transdate    
1   101         serviceuser1    2019-06-03   
2   101         serviceuser2    2019-06-03   
3   101         systemuser      2019-06-04   
4   102         serviceuser2    2019-06-03   
5   102         serviceuser2    2019-06-03   
6   102         serviceuser1    2019-06-05   
7   102         systemuser      2019-06-06   
8   103         serviceuser2    2019-06-03   
9   103         serviceuser1    2019-06-03   
10  103         systemuser      2019-06-06
```

Comment: @syncdm2012 - absolutely correct! flag is a boolean here :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - you need to change your `partition by` clause

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
SELECT ticketid,user,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ticketed,user order by transdate) AS rownumber FROM TableName 
) as temptable where rownumber=1
```

Comment: Thank you Fahmi..Really appriciate.